# Overriding a module that is used by a program I'm testing

Tags: perl, testing

I am revising a Perl program and I wanted a test harness that could run the original version of the program (call it `launch_rockets.pl`) and collect the standard output, but somehow skip the `system` calls that occur inside `launch_rockets.pl`.  The following code successfully overrides `system` inside `launch_rockets.pl`:

```
use subs qw(system);
my $SYSTEM_SUCCESS = 0;
sub system {
    print "***\n";
    print "system @_\n";
    print "***\n\n";
    return $SYSTEM_SUCCESS;
}
local @ARGV = @test_args;
do 'launch_rockets.pl';
```

So far so good.  But `launch_rockets.pl` also contains

```
use Proc::Background;
```

and later

```
Proc::Background->new('perl', 'launch_missiles.pl');
```

I could copy `launch_rockets.pl` into a sandbox where `Proc::Background` is replaced by a stub, but I was wondering if there was any override strategy that would be effective inside a `do FILE` call in the file's original environment.

Comment: Good answer here from cjm, but let me share an alternative someone suggested on [PerlMonks]http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=875964: instead of tampering with `%INC`, I can achieve the same effect by pre-empting the loading of the module.  I just say `use Proc::Background;` in the calling code, redefine `Proc::Background::new`, and then I can securely make my `do FILE` call.

Comment: That can work, but you have to be careful.  Since you're loading the real module and then monkey-patching it, if you miss something you should have patched, the genuine code will run, and may do something you didn't want.  My approach prevents the real module from loading, so if you miss something, you'll just get an error about "no such function" or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use lib '/my/test/library/path';
```

[lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?lib) prepends the directory to `@INC`, so `/my/test/library/path/Proc/Background.pm` will be the file that gets loaded.  Put whatever code you want in there.

Another alternative would be:

```
{
  package Proc::Background;
  ... # Put stub code here
} # end of package Proc::Background
$INC{'Proc/Background.pm'} = 1; # Make Perl think Proc::Background is loaded
```